# Django annotate Multiple Sum and group By

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

let's take this model:

```
class Server(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    cpu = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    ram = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
    Customer,
    related_name='Servers',
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    null=True,
    blank=True
    )
    city = models.ForeignKey(
    City,
    related_name='Servers',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    null=True,
    blank=True
    )


class Disk(models.Model):
    server = models.ForeignKey(
        Server,
        related_name='Disks',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=False,
        blank=False
    )
    size = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(null=False, blank=False)


class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,
                            blank=True, null=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(
        blank=False, null=False, default=False)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,
                            blank=False, null=False)
    country = models.ForeignKey(
        Country,
        related_name='Cities',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=False,
        blank=False
    )
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,
                            blank=False, null=False)
```

I would like to know how many Server with the sum of every CPU, RAM, Disk space I have per customer per country.

- Every Server has a city, every city is in a country.
- Some Server has no customer yet, but I still need to know how many server, CPU, ... I have with no customer (can eventually create an "Unknown" Customer to not set it to None in Server).

Any Help will be appreciated ! Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I can help as I think it's too experimental to do without tests.

For example, annotate the country and your server count:

```
Server.objects.annotate(get_country=F("city__country")).values("get_country").annotate(count=Count('get_country'))
```

Now from here, if your result is like [{"countryA":150, "countryB": 17, ....}]
you can proceed and replace the count with

```
Server.objects.annotate(get_country=F("city__country")).values("get_country").annotate(sum_cpu=Sum('cpu'), sum_ram=Sum('ram'), sum_disk=Sum('disk__size'))
```

Now since you want this to be per customer, you would have to reformat it to start with the customer model instead of the server model.

Or depending how you show the data your query can start with
`Server.objects.filter(customer=customer_obj).annotate....`